# Can i launch solaris EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, solaris

I need to launch solaris os in aws-ec2,
1) Do aws provide solaris ami? 
My analysis-i searched but not found anywhere in aws marketplace.

2) can i create vm of solaris in local and than export to aws-ec2 using AWS VM import-export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten years ago EC2 only supported Linux natively.  AWS supplied the kernel, and the kernel was Linux 2.6.16 at that point in time.  Right now AWS support other operating systems.  Some users have had a lot of success running other OS's (e.g. Windows, but Solaris should also work) on top of the native Linux instances we provide, using emulation software like QEMU.  For example see Enomaly (www.anomaly.net), and various postings resources on this  Amazon Web Services site, e.g.

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=47267
http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=592&categoryID=101
http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry!default.jspa?categoryID=100&externalID=507&fromSearchPage=true

Via Amazon.com

Answer (score 5):

According to this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/ec2/entry/oracle_solaris_on_amazon_ec2), no. Looks like they stopped supporting it back in 2011.

Comment: can i create vm of solaris in local and than export to aws-ec2 using AWS VM import-export?

Comment: I have a feeling that won't work either. Its probably has something to do with the virtualization layer.  But you can always try it out and let us know. Rarely hurts to try something.

Comment: yes.. it worked created vm of solaris in local and than export to aws-ec2 using AWS VM import-export, thanks @george